# Stop request from reaching Controller in BeginRequest

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Some of my requests look like this:

```
http://mydomain.com/?q=value
```

And are handled in BeginRequest.
I don't want these requests to reach the Home.Index Controller Action which renders the home page.

I tried using

```
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

or

```
Requst.End();
```

But the problem with these is that they cutoff the pipeline completely preventing other code from executing, specifically analytics done by NewRelic which hook on the pipeline events.

So how can I prevent only the controller from executing after handling the request in BeginRequest ?

Comment: What do you want to happen at this point? What should be returned to the client?

Comment: I set the response in the BeginRequest method using Response.Write().
After that I don't want any additional Actions appending content to the Response stream. But as I said before, using Response.End() will also break Analytics code that depend on the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I found so far is adding a global action filter with

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new GlobalActionAbortAttribute ());
```

On the BeginRequest I mark the current context with a flag

```
Context.Items["SkipRequest"] = true;
```

and in the filter I filter out all action when the flag is present

```
public class GlobalActionAbortAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if ((bool?)HttpContext.Current.Items["SkipRequest"] == true)
            filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult();
        else
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would seem a simpler option here is to allow the request to reach the controller and detect this scenario and simply return Content() rather than your view.

You could also  try to setup a custom querystring route constraint that looks for this parameter, if its there, redirects to a controller that does your operation and returns Content() - you can see querystring constraint sample code here: [Can my MVC2 app specify route constraints on Query String parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269046/can-my-mvc2-app-specify-route-constraints-on-query-string-parameters)

Comment: I can't use routing because only some of the requests with the query are handled in the BeginRequest method, it depends on the content of the query values and the logic is too complex to express with the routing syntax (requires programmatic validation).