# routes.MapRoute not working for a form submitted with GET

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a form that represents a dropdown list of things. You select the desired thing and hit the okay button. It submits the form using a GET and the resulting URL is:

/Something/IdentificationInformation?jamesID=26

So I applied a routing rule:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: null, // "Add James relationship"
            url: "James/IdentificationInformation/{jamesID}",
            defaults: new { 
                Controller = "James",
                action = "IdentificationInformation"
            }
        );
```

but this url route does not get applied?

The form being submitted looks like this:

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("IdentificationInformation", "James", FormMethod.Get))
        {
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 add-margin-top">
                    @Html.DropDownList("jamesID", new SelectList(Model, "JamesID", "Name"), new { id = "JamesDropdownList" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 add-margin-top">
                @Html.ContinueButton("Continue")
            </div>
        }
```

Comment: Anything I can add to this question to help get an answer? it's a bit odd.

Comment: Do you have any routes defined before this one that might be matched first? Also, in your Html.BeginForm() it looks like the controller is JamesController ...

Comment: No routes before, no. That was a typo, sorry and thanks for picking up on that. I've ended up having to do 2 controllers, one that takes a POST request from the form, then that redirects to another controller that returns the view. It's like the routing rules do not work for Form submits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your route expects `jamesID` to be part of the url path but the form submits it as part of the querystring. If you change your route to something like this, it should match:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: null, // "Add James relationship"
        url: "James/IdentificationInformation",
        defaults: new { 
            Controller = "James",
            action = "IdentificationInformation"
        }
    );
```

And, of course, this route probably isn't even necessary since it's equivalent to the default route of {controller}/{action}.

If you want to get fancy, you could define a custom QueryStringConstraint to ensure that jamesID is in the querystring as part of the route matching. Here's a SO question that shows how to do that:

[Can my MVC2 app specify route constraints on Query String parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269046/can-my-mvc2-app-specify-route-constraints-on-query-string-parameters)

Comment: Thanks... It makes sense as to why... shame it's such a bother to implement :) . My current solution is 2 controller methods. One that takes a POST request from the form, then that redirects to another controller method that returns the view. 2 requests for one page just for a pretty URL... I guess the answer is it's a poor work around. I'll see if I can implement your idea.